# While refreshing, duplicate data inserts into DB in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have inserted data into my table using `$this->db->insert()`. When the data inserted successfully the message have to display, also the data should not insert again.

controller:

```
public function index($message = '') {
    $this->load->template('homePage');
}

/**
 * Insert functionlaity
 */
public function insert() {
    if ($_POST['save']) {
        $result = $this->home->insertEntry();
        $data['message'] = ($result > 0) ? 'saved' : 'Not';
        redirect('HomeController',$data);
    }
    $this->load->view('homePage');
}
```

Model:

```
public function insertEntry()
{
    $this->name    = $_POST['name'];
    $this->email   = $_POST['email'];
    $this->db->insert('users', $this);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();

}
```

View:

```
    <div class="container sampleForm"><?php
echo isset ($message) ? $message : '';
echo form_open( get_class(get_instance()) . '/insert')
 . form_label('id') . form_input('id', isset($query['id']) ? $query['id'] : '', 'class="form-control"') . br()
 . form_label('name') . form_input('name', isset($query['name']) ? $query['name'] : '', 'class="form-control"') . br()
 . form_label('email') . form_custom_input('email','email', isset($query['email']) ? $query['email'] : '', 'class="form-control"') . br()
 . form_submit('save', 'save', 'class="btn btn-primary"')
 . form_close();
?> </div>
```

My issue is if i can display status then data insert for every refresh else status will not be displayed.

This all should works in my HomeController.php as controller, Home.php as model and homePage.php as view file. Not in any other files.

My logic is:

Ex: I have a student table in that i am gonna to store student names and marks like `name, m1, m2, m3`. Now I want to add marks if its added i want to display the status. Duplicate insertion should not happen while refresh the page. The student name and marks were similar. I want to do in php alone.

Comment: I couldnt understand your issue, is it that when you redirect what happens actually is the form will be submitted again and inserted?

Comment: For me data have to insert once and status  has to display after insertion..

Comment: ok, why dont you try to submit the form via Ajax, this is what i usually do in forms, this way you can validate them easily, and then based on the response of your function in the controller, you will decide whether to show a successful message or not using jquery and javascript

Comment: But i want it from only using php

Comment: just check before insert if the data exists or not at your database.

Comment: i have updated the code and added my logic please check this case.

Comment: I thing you have to give the uniqueness of each student records like id(primary key value) or something.  I see you added Id you can check with that if the Id is present or not. 
In your case and given example there should be unique value for each student. 

I'm interested to know which solution you will get. It increasing my curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, There is no option to pass the status(success, error) messages to the overview page(or desired page).

Use the $_SESSION to holds the values and retrieve values from the session.

To show the status Message and avoid the duplicate entries, The code as follows:

CONTROLLER:

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $result = $this->home->insertEntry();
    $message = ($result > 0) ? 'saved' : 'Not';
    $this->session->set_userdata('message', $message);
    //redirect, avoid duplicate entries
    redirect('HomeController');
}
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="container sampleForm"><?php
    if($this->session->has_userdata('message')){
        echo $this->session->message;
        $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
    }

    echo form_open( get_class(get_instance()) . '/insert')
     . form_label('id') . form_input('id', isset($query['id']) ? $query['id'] : '', 'class="form-control"') . br()
     . form_label('name') . form_input('name', isset($query['name']) ? $query['name'] : '', 'class="form-control"') . br()
     . form_label('email') . form_custom_input('email','email', isset($query['email']) ? $query['email'] : '', 'class="form-control"') . br()
     . form_submit('save', 'save', 'class="btn btn-primary"')
     . form_close();
    ?> </div>
```

Comment: pls explain in detail about your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In Controller :

```
public function inserttest() {
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $result = $this->admin_model->insertEntry();     
       if($result>0) {
          // values are saved in session to display the message.
          $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Save');
       } else {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'No');
       }
       // To avoid duplicate redirect to another page
       redirect('admin/user/inserttest');
   } else {
       $this->load->view('admin/test');
   }
}
```

Model:

```
public function insertEntry()
{
     $data=array(

     'id'=>$_POST['id'],
     'name'=>$_POST['name'],
     'email'=>$_POST['email'],

     );


    $this->db->insert('test_check',$data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();

}
```

View:

```
<html>
    <body>
       <?php  if(isset($this->session->flashdata('message'))){ 
              echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); 
              }
       ?>
  <form action="" method="post">

    Id:<input type="text" name="id">

    Name:<input type="text" name="name">
    Email<input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit"  value="submit"  name="submit">

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

read this for more about flashdata:  ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: by using  set_flashdata you can shoe msg

Comment: Can you please explain.

Comment: on controller user this after result  if($insert_id>0)
     {
    $this -> session -> set_flashdata('green_message', 'Emergency info Updated successfully.');
    
     }
      else
   { 
        $this -> session -> set_flashdata('red_message', 'Emergency info not Updated successfully.'); 
     
   }

Comment: on view to show msg  <?php
       
       if($this->session->flashdata('green_message'))
       {
        ?>
         <div class="col-lg-6 alert alert-success">
                                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('green_message'); ?> 
                            </div>
        
      <?php  
       }

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use below code to resolved the duplicate entry for email

```
if(!empty($submit))
{
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); die;
    $data = $this->get_data_from_post();
    $unique_email = '|is_unique['.TBL_USERS.'.email]';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[12]|xss_clean|htmlentities|prep_for_form|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email|htmlentities|prep_for_form'.$unique_email);
    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE ){ 
        $data['name']    = $_POST['name'];
        $data['email']   = $_POST['email'];
        $res = $this->mdl_customer->_insert($data);
        redirect('home'); // where you want to redirect.
    }
}
```

By doing this the user who refreshes will be refreshing landing_page.php which means it won't do the insert twice.
best advice: do a check to see if user exists first if so don't insert!

Once an insert or update is done in your code you always need to redirect to another page.

Comment: Please,understand my question well. Entries are repeating when refresh. Not asking for validation

Comment: or Just uncomment the redirect code and set your success or error message in session.

$result = $this->home->insertEntry();
$data['message'] = $result ? 'saved' : 'Not';
redirect('HomeController');

Comment: I have to throw the status if its inserted or Not

Answer (score 0):

Call this function to open the view page as well as on submit, leave the `action=""` it checks that you submit the data or only access the view page, but this data will not inset on refresh

```
function add()
{
   if(isset($_POST{['submit']))
    {
     $result = $this->home->insertEntry();
     $data['message'] = $result ? 'saved' : 'Not';  
     redirect('add',$data);

    }

    $this->load->view('view page');  

}
```

Comment: If i removed action form is not submit with the exact function. Also if value inserted then it redirects means then can't display status message.

Comment: use the same controller to open the view and when you submit the form (leave action=" ")  it will automatically redirect you on the same function and checks if it for the submit form or to load the view.

Comment: I have added more code for good understanding also added my logic. Please look into this.

Comment: try if (isset($_POST['save']))
 in place of if ($_POST['save'])

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = $this->home->insertEntry();
$data['message'] = $result ? 'saved' : 'Not';
$this->load->view('Your View page name ',$data);
```

and use the below code in you view page to display message

```
if(isset($message))
{
  echo $message;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, this case the entry will save repeatedly